# Pygame invisible Color

Tags: python-2.7, colors, pygame

Is there any way of defining an invisible Color in pygame, so that calling it on `screen.fill(invisibleColor,pygame.mouse.get_pos())` wouldn't cover the drawings behind it?

Comment: You could try use a RBGA colour with a transparency of 100%.

Comment: How can i make the transparency 100%? Using colors like (255,255,255,255) (with the alpha argument) doesn't help

Comment: Alpha of 255 is entirely opaque -- try (255,255,255,0) instead?

Comment: Ah, hang on - do you mean you have a solid rectangle and you want just a smaller rectangle under the mouse to "create a hole" through which you can see the things under the solid rectangle?

Answer (score 2):

There are three different methods for transparency in Python; looking at [The documentation for fill](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) it looks like you will need to pass the special flags into the last parameter to support whichever transparency method you are using.

What I found useful was to use the `convert_alpha()` function [Documented here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) rather than `convert` on my surfaces; I discovered that in my case the transparency wasn't working because I was using regular `convert`.

ADDITIONAL:

I'm not 100% clear on what you are trying to achieve, but it occurs to me that you may mean you want only a rectangle under the mouse to be visible and you mean to use transparency to do that. If that is the case there are a couple of problems:

- A transparent colour is just that - transparent - drawing it over an existing sold rectangle will allow you to see that solid rectangle through your transparent colour; in other words it will be exactly the same as not having that rectangle drawn in the first place
- You will be drawing an entire screen and then covering it; this will be slow.

If this is what you are trying to achieve, you may do better to just render a smaller surface (the bit that's under the mouse) and draw that to the screen over your solid background.

If you really do want to draw a solid rectangle with a hole under the mouse you will need to draw four rectangles like this (sorry for the ascii art):

```
 +------------------+
 |        1         |
 +------+---+-------+
 |  2   | m |   3   |
 +------+---+-------+
 |        4         |
 +------------------+
```

That way the bit of the screen under the mouse (marked `m` in the 'diagram') will not be covered by your solid colour, but the rectangles 1,2,3&4 will all appear to be one solid rectangle (with a hole under the mouse).

Hope this helps refine the answer to suit your needs.

Comment: `convert` and `convert_alpha` work on `Surface` objects. What if i want to have a transparent color to use on drawing a `Rect` (for example in `pygame.draw.rect(screen,COLOR,pygame.Rect)`)?

Comment: Drawing a transparent rectangle is exactly the same as not drawing the rectangle in the first place; it's a waste of computation (and I'd be trying to squeeze every bit of performance out of pygame that I could get). Do you mean you want it semi-transparent (ie an alpha >0)?